# Mutual Inclusion of Header Files

Tags: c++, xcode, header-files, inclusion

Let's say I have a header file called `inclusions.h` that has all the `#include <...>`s for my project.  `inclusions.h` includes another header file called `settings.h`, where various constants can be modified.

If `#include <math.h>` in `inclusions.h`, will `settings.h` have access to the math library as well?  Or do I have to `#include <math.h>` in `settings.h` as well?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: A little side note too, by default when you are programming in C for Microchip chips, they automatically do what you're suggesting for their HardwareProfile.h headers. They load a 'standard' header which you will modify to include the proper one needed for your setup. 

Sometimes things like this are done to keep 'standards' in place for a larger organization. AKA, in order to use xyz, include this specialized header, but if you need to do xzy, include this one. Personally... including all headers where specifically needed is the way I do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If math.h is included before settings.h, settings.h should also have access to math.h. But to ensure the access (and to indicate the dependencies), you should include the files where they are needed, so also in math.h.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Isn't it bad practice to include libraries more than once, though?

Comment: No, it's definitely not bad practice. On the contrary, including all possible headers within every other header using a central header file is bad practice. Just include the headers where they are needed and no more, but, if required, multiple times. The include guards prevent double-declarations anyway.

Comment: @Maxpm: That is what [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) are for.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the order of the inclusions. `#include` is a preprocessor directive that simply works by textual substitution. So, if in `inclusions.h` you have:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <settings.h>
```

settings "can see" math. If you have:

```
#include <settings.h>
#include <math.h>
```

it can't. But: what would happen if you used `settings.h` elsewhere *without* including `math.h` before? So in the end, try to make each include file independent.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, as others have noted, depending on the order of inclusion it could be accessible. This is because those source files are a part of one translation unit (source + includes essentially) so if `<math.h>` comes before `"settings.h"`, it could be viewable by it. However, if settings became a part of another translation unit, or if you decided to move certain includes around that could change. To be "safe", you should just included whatever header files which are necessary for a file to have in that file.